# Auto end html tags in Vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

The user enters a tag (like `<div>`), and JavaScript should end it (`</div>`).
It should also not do it for HTML tags like `<hello>`.

I've tried `str. repeat`, but it didn't come out as expected.
This is what I've tried:

```js
function inputtextarea() {
 let inputtextarea = document.getElementById('inputtextarea');
 inputtextarea.value = inputtextarea.value.repeat(2);
}
```

```html
<textarea name="inputtextarea" id="inputtextarea" cols="30" rows="10" oninput="inputtextarea()"></textarea>
```

Can you tell me why it is not working?

[link for `str.repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat)

Comment: I don't know your motivation and it isn't my position to question it, but I would still like to tell you that I can't stand editors that auto-close tags for me. So, if I may give a suggestion, at least have an option to turn it off. :)

Comment: `repeat` is a method of String, you're trying to call that method in the context of a textarea. Hit F12 to see what is going on in your code ...

Comment: `textarea.value` has no innerHTML. This is not a good way to achieve this. For one if I type anything in there as well as the tag, it is going to repeat that text too.

Comment: InnerHTML is not updated after the DOM load. I don't know what you want with this - But if you want to repeat the value every time that a user presses a key, then you need to modify you code like : `document.getElementById('inputtextarea').value = inputtextarea.repeat(2);` since `inputtextarea` is already targeting the value *EDIT* you changed the question after I wrote this, now you need to access the value again...

Comment: I didn't mean "change the entire code to this" I meant, *incorporate this into your code*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my attempt, with some work you should get something better.

Fixed some errors!

```js
function checkKeypress(elem, evt) {
    var txtBef = elem.value.slice(0, elem.selectionEnd);
    var txtAft = elem.value.slice(elem.selectionEnd, elem.value.lenth);
    var lastString = txtBef
        .replace(/\s+/g, " ") /*replace multiple spaces to just one*/
        .split(" ");
    lastString = lastString[lastString.length - 1];
    
    if(evt.key == ">"){
        if(lastString.includes("<")){
            var addClose = lastString.replace(/[< >]/g, ""); //replaces < and > to blank space
            elem.value = txtBef+"  </"+addClose+">"+txtAft; //closes the writed tag
            elem.selectionEnd = txtBef.length + 1; //places the cursor at the midle of the tags
        }
    }
}
```

```css
textarea {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
Write a existing or a custom HTML tag and this textarea will altomatically close it for  you!
<textarea onkeyup="checkKeypress(this, event)"></textarea>
```

Comment: Yeah, i just saw

Comment: Well, i got you the basic code, you shuold edit it to fullfill you needs.

Comment: this textarea doesn't work with a lot of space inside it and with multiple tags.

Comment: so, I think this could be a problem for a lot of tags....

Comment: maybe if you type in a ending tag?

Comment: Maybe on the txtBef, you can put something like or less than, and on txtAft greater than might work.

Comment: but, i don't know how.

Comment: It works for anything you type. It should be restricted to HTML tags only